# Why Proguard still work without proguard-base.jar in android studio

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

My Android Studio `version is 2.3`，and I find `proguard version` in my local

```
directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/m2repository/net/sf/proguard/proguard-base.
There are two version, 5.2.1 and 5.3.2
Now I delete 5.3.2 folder, but when I execute: "gradle build" command, the log message shows still use 5.3.2, like:
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease
:app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
ProGuard, version 5.3.2
Reading input...
```

I wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't set the option to disable proguard (which apperantly is enabled by default). Just add the option 
'minifyEnabled false' under defaultConfig closurr or the relevant buildType closure.

Answer (score 0):

ProGuard is now included in the Android Gradle Plugin and deleting the binaries in `m2repository` just makes Gradle download it again on the next build.

If you want to build with 5.2.1 then you'll have to downgrade the version of the Android Plugin back to 2.2:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
```

because version 2.3 includes ProGuard 5.3.2, as per their release notes:

> Android plugin for Gradle, revision 2.3.0 (February 2017)
>   ...
>   Plugin now uses ProGuard version 5.3.2.

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html